# grunt-wiredep and Jade templates

Tags: gruntjs, pug, wiredep

I'm successfully using the grunt-wiredep package to inject bower components into my view markup, and I'm currently porting the views from HTML to Jade. However, when I run my build script the bower scripts aren't injected into the page like they were when I was using HTML.

I've changed the `src` parameter to reference `index.jade` instead of `index.html`. Any ideas why the injection isn't working?

Comment: Please add your current configuration from your gruntfile otherwise we can't really help.

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar problem and looking at the regex it was not clear enough what to inject.
So I just add my solution here for others having the same problem.

In **jade** files you **need to add** :

```
  // bower:js
  // endbower
```

and **not** :
  `<!-- bower:css -->`
  `<!-- endbower -->`

For other file extension please search in the wiredep's [github test](https://github.com/taptapship/wiredep/tree/master/test/fixture) folder.

Comment: That's a good thing to note @nane. Another related gotcha is if your bower/inject tasks are running on an html file that was compiled from Jade by a previous task, Jade turns `// bower:js` into `<!-- bower:js-->` (no trailing space), which the regex doesn't match. Use html comments in your Jade file to get around this.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're running the latest version of wiredep `1.8.5` which adds Jade support.

Check out the [documentation](https://github.com/stephenplusplus/grunt-wiredep) as well as [the main readme](https://github.com/taptapship/wiredep/blob/master/readme.md) which provides more options.

**Update the following with your own view structure.**

```
wiredep: {

  target: {

    // Point to the files that should be updated when
    // you run `grunt wiredep`
    src: [
      'app/views/**/*.html',   // .html support...
      'app/views/**/*.jade',   // .jade support...
      'app/styles/main.scss',  // .scss & .sass support...
      'app/config.yml'         // and .yml & .yaml support out of the box!
    ],

    // Optional:
    // ---------
    options: {
      cwd: '',
      dependencies: true,
      devDependencies: false,
      exclude: [],
      fileTypes: {},
      ignorePath: '',
      overrides: {}
    }

  }

}
```